# Using property on many class attributes

Tags: python, oop, python-decorators

I have two classes that have many attributes, and all but one should have similar property functions. I prefer to avoid writing these properties manually for all the attributes, as this will be tedious and will force me to follow it up on each attribute that I add to the class. Also, I need to do it for more than one class.

I will use this after the object in my_container is generated. 
Below is a simplified example of the case I want to solve.

```
def my_class:            

  @property
  def a1(self):
    return self.my_container._a1
    ...
  @property
  def a10(self):
    return self.my_container._a10
```

Comment: Do they have to be properties? You could just implement a `__getattr__` function instead; `def __getattr__(self, name): return getattr(self, '_' + name)`.

Comment: I will need to implement setattr as well, and I prefer to avoid magic methods  on this code @MartijnPieters

Comment: Then your other option is to use either a class decorator or a metaclass to generate all those property objects.

Comment: For now I settled with `__getattr__`. This does make my code a bit more tedious. Are there downsides to overriding the function?
Thank you @MartijnPieters

Comment: No, as long as you don't try to access attributes that don't exist again in `__getattr__` and don't limit what names you respond to in `__getattr__` you won't cause an infinite recursion, then `__getattr__` is exactly the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a series of properties that follow a specific pattern, I'd use a `__getattr__` hook:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    # translate a\d names into _a\d
    if name.startswith('a') and name[1:].isdigit():
        return getattr(self, '_' + name)
```

This presumes that it isn't easier to just set those attributes *directly* (so adding `a0` instead of `_a0`), e.g. when you also have a corresponding `__setattr__` that handles gating or transformations on setting those same attributes.